# Change the size of a view controller on the storyboard?

Tags: xcode, view, controller

How can I change the size of a view controller in an Xcode Storyboard for editing purposes?

I have a bunch of elements in my storyboard and it would be much easier if I could make it bigger.  I'm used to Photoshop and other graphical programs that let you increase the size to a more usable one.

I can zoom it out to 100%, but I'd really like the size to be twice as big.

Please note, I want to change the VIEWING size on View controller, NOT the actual size (Simulated Metrics, etc.)

PS.  Yes, I know I can use accessibility settings and make my entire desktop larger, but that's a cheap fix to the problem.

Comment: u can try freeform view controller

Comment: Thank you Mr. T.  But doesn't that change the ACTUAL size of the View Controller?  All I want to do is make the Storyboard larger.  If I change to the freeform view controller and move my elements out of a 4.7 inch box and compile in an iPhone 6 screen, then my elements will appear out of the frame

Answer (score 5):

First click on View controller and select Size Inspector tab, in Simulated size select freeform and change the width and height.

[image]

I see you comment above about not wanting the above suggestion I posted (simulated>freeform).
Do you mean 'use size classes' ? Size classes allows you to change to different iPhone or iPad sizes during your design to fit what you need. See picture below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think I'm explaining myself properly. I want to keep a 4.7 inch screen on iPhone 6S.  However on the viewing area (aka storyboard) I simply want to make the image larger.  Right now the max is 100%, but I want it to be (a theoretical) 150% or 200%. I have small elements on the screen and I'd like to be able to place them more efficiently.